# Put the same type constraints on multiple types at once

Tags: generics, rust

I have a lot of type constraints, and I would like to make it more readable. For example, is there a way to simplify this:

```
<P: Serialize + Clone + Eq + std::hash::Hash + std::fmt::Display, E: Serialize + Clone + Eq + std::hash::Hash + std::fmt::Display>
```

Can I remove this duplication somehow, maybe with a `where` statement to make it something like this:

```
where P + E: Serialize + Clone + Eq + std::hash::Hash + std::fmt::Display
```

It just seems wrong to have it so large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not currently any way to combine type constraints like you're hoping for. However, you can at least consolidate the boilerplate a little bit by defining your own trait and a blanket implementation, like this:

```
trait Data: Serialize + Clone + Eq + std::hash::Hash + std::fmt::Display {}
impl<T> Data for T where T: Serialize + Clone + Eq + std::hash::Hash + std::fmt::Display {}
```

This will then allow you to write type constraints like this:

```
where P: Data, E: Data
```

Note that the original type constraints must still be replicated on both the trait definition and the implementation, to ensure that 1. types implementing the trait also expose the necessary behavior, and 2. the implementation only applies to types that implement the necessary traits.

[Here's an example in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3366e0bc6bb634567759072c594ca1c4).

Comment: Ah, thanks. Wish there was something to make it less hacky. Guess I'll just stay with what I have then.

Comment: There's the [trait alias RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1733-trait-alias.md) which would simplify this pattern somewhat, but it's only available in nightly right now and not likely to be stabilized for a while unfortunately.